# docusign api envelope expiration

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

can you please help me with below query:
I am using demo login. I am trying to send a document for signatures using java. I need to set the expiration on my envelope as 1 day. I tried using below but it did not set the expiration on my envelope.

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<emailSubject>Contract for Signature</emailSubject>
<status>sent</status>
<notification>
    <expirations>
        <expiration>
            <expirationEnabled>true</expirationEnabled>
            <expirationAfter>1</expirationAfter>
            <expirationWarn>1</expirationWarn>
        </expiration>
    </expirations>
</notification>
<documents>
    <document>
        <name>  documentName  </name>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
        <order>1</order>
    </document>
</documents>
<recipients>
    <signers>
        <signer>
            <email>  custEmail  </email>
            <name> recipientNameCust  </name>
            <recipientId>1</recipientId>
            <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
            <tabs>
                <signHereTabs>
                    <signHere>
                        <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of the Customer</anchorString>
                        <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
                        <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset>
                        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                        <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
                        <documentId>1</documentId>
                        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                        <tabLabel>Sign Here1</tabLabel>
                        <name>SignHere1</name>
                    </signHere>
                </signHereTabs>
            </tabs>
        </signer>
        <signer>
            <email>  receipientEmail  </email>
            <name>  recipientNameTotal  </name>
            <recipientId>2</recipientId>
            <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
            <tabs>
                <signHereTabs>
                    <signHere>
                        <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of Total</anchorString>
                        <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
                        <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset>
                        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                        <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
                        <documentId>1</documentId>
                        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
                        <tabLabel>Sign Here2</tabLabel>
                        <name>SignHere2</name>
                    </signHere>
                </signHereTabs>
            </tabs>
        </signer>
    </signers>
</recipients>
```

The api documentation says the tags as -expireEnabled instead of expirationEnabled, expireAfter instead of expirationAfter, expireWarn instead of expirationWarn. So I have tried with these tags also and it still did not work. Can you please let me know if anything is wrong with the above xml.
In the portal under Account Administration/Set default reminders expirations the check box "do not allow users to override" is not checked. Also Expire/void Envelope is set to 2 days. But all my envelopes are getting created with expiration setting as 120 days.

Comment: It worked with below: Please ignore above query.
<notification>
<expirations>
<expireEnabled>true</expireEnabled>
<expireAfter>1</expireAfter>
<expireWarn>0</expireWarn>
</expirations>
</notification>

Thanks.

Comment: Example in the REST API Guide needs a correction.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following XML:

```
<notification>
   <expirations>
      <expireEnabled>true</expireEnabled>
      <expireAfter>1</expireAfter>
      <expireWarn>0</expireWarn>
   </expirations>
</notification>
```